# In Python's try... else... clause, why is the else claused parsed if try fails?

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm coming across an issue with try... else... I'm testing that a variable has been set using `try`. If it has not been set, I just want to continue with the loop. If the variable has been set, I want to run the `else` part. However, Python throws a wobbly because it's trying to do the operations in the `else` part and failing because the variable has not been set. A bit of a Catch-22? Is there an alternative solution?

Code:

```
test = None
for num, line in enumerate(dataFile, 0):
    if myString in line:
        test = num
    try:
        test
    except:
        pass
    else:
        if (num - test) <= 58:
            ... do something ...
```

Comment: I can't replicate this problem.  Could you provide a minimal working example?

Comment: Or in this case, a minimal non-working example?  Something that I can copy/paste and experience this error for myself?

Comment: It is easily replicated like [this](http://i.gyazo.com/c92be2690949d4bbbaad3f5d1423089d.png). @Brionius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an `if` statement to check if `test` exists as something other than a `NoneType`.

```
test = None
for num, line in enumerate(dataFile, 0):
    if myString in line:
        test = num
    if test is not None:
        if (num - test) <= 58:
            # do something
```

Or just getting rid of a second `if` statement entirely.

```
for num, line in enumerate(dataFile, 0):
    if (myString in line) and ((num - test) <= 58):
        # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

Walking through your code... I'll simplify it a little bit to this:

```
foo = None

if foo:
    print 'Foo is not None'   # We never run this
try:
    foo    # This doesn't do anything, so this segment of the try / except will always end here
except:
    print 'The try segment did not raise an error'   # We also never get here
else:
    print 'Foo is none'   # We end up here because Foo is none, so this will print
```

Essentially... your `try / except` clause has no relevance to the `if / then` statement.  This is because of your indentation.

So in your example `if mystring not in line` then everything in the `else` statement will execute.

You can much more easily check for a variable not being set like this:

```
if not foo:
    # Do something with foo if it doesn't exist
else:
    # Continue running your loop since foo was set
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in your code you will not have an exception because test variable was created. As you never have a exception, the else clause always will be executed (this is what means the else in a try/except clause: run this part of the code if no exception was raised here).

If you just wanna know if a variable was setted and if it was not just continue the loop, you could do something like this:

```
# ...
for num, line in enumerate(dataFile, 0):
    # ...
    try: 
        test
    except NameError:
        # here you say 'skip the rest of loop in case of test was not setted'
        continue
   # here the rest of the code
```

In your case, maybe a easier way of doing the same is:

```
for num, line in enumerate(dataFile, 0):
    if myString in line:
        # in your code, if myString in line, test = num. So, num - test will allways be < 58 when myString in line

        # do something
```